# Print from python/PHP

Tags: php, python, printing

So, long story short, I have a site running in my home off a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian) (secured and not shared with anyone other than me, local within the network) running a down-and-dirty file upload system. I want to configure the server to automatically send any file I send to it to the printer, and print out automatically. I have CUPS installed on the pi, but I have no idea what else to do.

the printer is a wifi printer (Xerox colorcube) if that matters

I was thinking possibly a python script?

Comment: Do you have a question more specific than what you are thinking?

Comment: @KlausD. Honestly, I don't really know where to start other than this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I completed the task, and I am sharing this so any voyagers who stumble across this page don't find it unanswered.

Get the solution at [the github repo](https://github.com/jackcrane/pi-print)